# EMacs gdb command returns unknown message

Tags: emacs, gdb

I am new to EMacs and I'm having trouble starting the gdb debugger.

With the source file open, I enter M-x gdb (Alt-x gdb).  The minibuffer shows:

```
Run gdb like this:  gdb -i=mi   C_Cygwin.c
```

When I ENTER (RET), the minibuffer shows:

```
Searching for program: No such file or directory, gdb
```

This response is not mentioned in the EMacs manual, which only refers to the command M-x gdb.  A tutorial at https://kb.iu.edu/d/aqsy says that after M-x gdb, I should be prompted to enter "gdb (program_name)."  That's not what I get.

I am running EMacs in Cygwin, and the cygwin path is set to the path of the file I have open.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: are you able to start gdb directly from cygwin terminal (no using Emacs) ?

Comment: The problem was that I set the cygwin path to the path of the source file I want to debug (as I said in my question above).  Instead, do not change the cygwin path before opening emacs; when in emacs, open the source file using its whole path (in my case that's /our_files/C_Cygwin/C_Cygwin.c,  where "our_files" is a folder under the Cygwin root).  After the file is loaded that way, the call to gdb works correctly.